# PHP foreach loop to populate dropdown list with values that exclude certain results

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. **Enrollment** and **Product**. I want to list **Product** on a `<select>`.

Within this `<select>`, I only want certain **Product** items to appear, whereby the condition is to read from **Enrollment** table's **ProductID** which is a foreign key to Product table.

How does one exclude certain results in a `<select>` that had already existed in a different table?

```
<?php
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY ProductID ASC';
    $result_select = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_select))
    $rows[] = $row;
    echo "<div class=\"spanstyle\">Add course/product:<select name='add_product'>";
    echo "<option selected>Choose here</option>";
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['ProductID']."'>" . $row['ProductName']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></div>";
    $select1 = $_POST['add_product'];
    if (!strpos($select1, 'Choose here')) {
        $sql3="INSERT into enrollment (StudentID, ProductID) VALUES ($StudentID, $select1)";
        mysql_query($sql3);
        }
?>
```

Comment: Definitely perform this filtering in mysql.  The best way to do this will only require 1 query call.

Comment: do not use old mysql api - deprecated in 5.x, removed in 7.x

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reaction is that you need to modify your SQL query here, not the PHP loop. Something like (and this is a quick first shot so don't trust it without testing)

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE ProductID NOT IN (SELECT ProductID from enrollments) ORDER BY ProductID ASC`

This would exclude any row in `product` whose `ProductID` also appears in the `enrollments` table.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, but I don't get any result back at the select option. That's because I have another data column that triggers the result back to me `StudentID`. The sql statement does not read into which student I am currently reading from.

Comment: Here is my edited sql statement going by ur logic of changing the sql statement. `SELECT * FROM product WHERE ProductID NOT IN (SELECT ProductID from enrollment WHERE StudentID = "$StudentID") ORDER BY ProductID ASC`
I got incorrect results.

Comment: Fixed it. I have to use double quotes for my sql statement that is called from the variable.`"SELECT * FROM product WHERE ProductID NOT IN (SELECT ProductID from enrollment WHERE StudentID = '$StudentID') ORDER BY ProductID ASC";`